# ios authorization question

Tags: iphone, ipad, authentication, ios

Is it possible to restrict access to certain views within a native IOS app? For example, if a user authenticates against a web service from an iPad app, can that user then be restricted from seeing certain portions of the app based on their role? how does one go about this?

Comment: How do you plan on storing the user information? Plist? SQlite?

Comment: considering Im new to the IOS world....Im open to suggestions...is there a "best practice" when it comes to this type of thing? does apple provide any guidance?

Comment: Apple provides a lot of sample source code. You may need to read over the guidelines and other docs they provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for a token from the web service.  Hide objects and hide controls that would display objects or views if you don't get the correct token back from the web service.  You just can set the isHidden property of most any UI object to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a Security label to the user, and if the label matches a certain level, then grant access.

Comment: Thanks for the response...could you please provide a little more info in regard to your suggestion above? Im not sure that Im following your thinking.